# git log не показывает все коммиты

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

Я делаю последовательно 2 коммита и, в зависимости от того, на какой коммит переключаюсь, `git log` даёт разный вывод.

В рабочий директории находится один файл `main.txt` 
Я делаю:

```
$ git add main.txt 
$ git commit -m 'first commit'
```

Затем меняю содержимое `main.txt` и ещё раз делаю коммит:

```
$ git add main.txt 
$ git commit -m 'second commit'
```

Теперь, насколько я понимаю, у меня история из 2ух коммитов. И если cейчас сделать `git log`, то действительно, печатает 2 коммита и `HEAD` указывает на коммит, в котором я сейчас нахожусь:

```
$ git log
commit 43d08e5d2a2508d913ff4550ac5c6b51b190603e (HEAD -> master)
Author: User <user@company.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 19 16:24:07 2019 +0300

    second commit

commit 8515c37a95ed127b27f8637d0ee5a1de887281e3
Author: User <user@company.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 19 16:22:35 2019 +0300

    first commit
```

Однако, если переключиться на предыдущий коммит (first commit):

```
$ git checkout 8515c37a95ed12
```

то теперь вывод `git log` будет содержать лишь 1 коммит:

```
$ git log
commit 8515c37a95ed127b27f8637d0ee5a1de887281e3 (HEAD)
Author: User <user@company.com>
Date:   Thu Dec 19 16:22:35 2019 +0300

    first commit
```

хотя здесь я ожидал увидеть так же 2 коммита

Так и должно быть? Если да, и `git log` действительно не показывает все коммиты и всю истроию, то как это узнать, вне зависимости от того на каком коммите я нахожусь?

Comment: Попробуйте `git log --all`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, работает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, так и должно быть. Команда `git log` без параметров показывает список коммитов, начиная с текущего, то есть с того, на который указывает `HEAD`, и затем его предков. Когда вы запустили `git checkout 8515c37a95ed12`, вы переместили `HEAD` на этот коммит и поэтому сделанный после него коммит вам не виден.

Если вы хотите посмотреть всю историю, со всеми бранчами, запустите `git log --all` или `git log --all --graph`.

Если вы хотите ограничиться каким-то бранчем, то запустите `git log --first-parent <branch_name>`.